# Why can't I call the default super.init() on UIViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

I am not using a `UIViewController` from a storyboard and I want to have a custom `init` function where I pass in an `NSManagedObjectID` of some object. I just want to call `super.init()` like I have in Objective-C. Like this:

```
init(objectId: NSManagedObjectID) {
    super.init()
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

> Must call designated initializer of the superclass UIViewController

Can I simply not do this anymore?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The designated initialiser for `UIViewController` is `initWithNibName:bundle:`. You should be calling that instead.

See http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/real-iphone-crap-2-initwithnibnamebundle-is-the-designated-initializer-of-uiviewcontroller/

If you don't have a nib, pass in `nil` for the nibName (bundle is optional too). Then you could construct a custom view in `loadView` or by adding subviews to `self.view` in `viewDidLoad`, same as you used to.

Comment: So it is currently impossible for me to make a custom init method in a UIViewController subclass that is not from a nib?

Comment: Ahh, thanks!!  I was passing in "" for the nib name.

Comment: Overriding `initWithNibName:bundle:` alone is not enough; the compiler will throw an error and suggest you also implement the (required) `initWithCoder:`. I guess both are designated initializers? But only `withCoder` gets marked as "required" in swift...

Comment: Oh, after a little digging,  it turns out `initWithCoder:` comes from the `NSCoding` protocol... I still can't figure out what's its role in initializing a UIViewController instance, whether it is a "designated" initializer of UIViewController or any of its superclasses...

Comment: Thanks! For quick copy/paste just call this after setting your `let` properties, if any: `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`.

Comment: Init With coder is used for when you need to do state restoration. When you save the state of the viewcontroller by using the state restoration functionality, the coder will return the values you saved when the state was saved. From there you can rebuild the view controller to its last initial state from when you closed out the application. So to the user its where they left off from

Answer (score 50):

Another nice solution is to declare your new initializer as a `convenience` initializer as follows:

```
convenience init( objectId : NSManagedObjectID ) {
    self.init()

    // ... store or user your objectId
}
```

If you declare no designated initializers in your subclass at all, they are inherited automatically and you are able to use `self.init()` within your convenience initializer.

In case of UIViewController the default init method will call `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)` with `nil` for both arguments (Command-Click on UIViewController will give you that info).

**TL;TR**: If you prefer to programmatically work with `UIViewController`s here is a complete working example that adds a new initializer with a custom argument:

```
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController {
    var myString: String = ""

    convenience init( myString: String ) {
        self.init()

        self.myString = myString
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution and works in any generic case

Comment: I tried doing this in an extension, and it recursively called itself.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin when you provide your code as a gist, I can tell you why.

Comment: The "trick" to this answer is that `myString` is set to `""` so the `init` is not required. This solution falls apart if you don't want to use an initial value, and in that case you need to use `self.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)`

Comment: @Yar or you make the `myString` property an optional

Comment: @Klaas yes: my issue is that I was using the initializers ONLY to avoid optionals and get my code to compile.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin (and others): see my answer [in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43525331/5951226) to solve the infinite recursion problem.

Answer (score 36):

To improve the **occulus's** answer:

```
init() {
     super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 18):

**Update:  add the link**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init

According to the documentation for iOS, the designated initialiser for UIViewController is `initWithNibName: bundle:`.

> If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this method, even if you aren't using a NIB.

**You can do it as follows:**

```
init(objectId : NSManagedObjectID) {

    super.init(nibName: (xib's name or nil'), bundle: nil)

   // other code...
}
```

**or**

Declare a new initializer as a convenience initializer:

```
 convenience init( objectId : NSManagedObjectID ) {

    self.init()

     // other code...
```

}

[image]

Comment: You should link to the original for attribution, rather than leaving it as a screencap.

Comment: I used the same process as @NcNc said. It worked for me. Here's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997236/super-init-isnt-called-on-all-paths-before-returning-from-initializer/45920375#45920375)

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, he should not. Links has a feature to expire or move someday. Who wants to see a 404 error instead of an information he/she is looking for?

Comment: @mykolaj: The information is *already* here, in this answer. (Otherwise I would have been flagging for deletion as a link-only answer.) But attribution is also important so that anyone who reads this can find out where it came from and credit them. A screenshot does not work for that, but a link does. If a link rots, well that's unfortunate, but you can't possibly tell me that's a worse situation than never having any kind of credit given at all. The objections SO has to link-only answers are to link-**only** answers. Not to links. Link *and also* info is the desired formulation.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I just added the link.  Thanks for your reminding