# super init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I made a framework that wraps Alamofire.

In my Framework when testing (in Test target) i have this code that works grate.

```
import Foundation
@testable import NetworkManager

class MockRouter: Router {


enum APICalls {
    case func1
    case func2
}

var calls: APICalls!

init(calls: APICalls) {
    self.calls = calls
}

}
```

When i add it as a framework to a different project

```
import Foundation
import NetworkManager

class JokesRouter: Router {

enum APICalls {
    case func1
    case func2
}

var calls: APICalls!

init(calls: APICalls) {
    self.calls = calls
}


}
```

I get an error:

> super init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

So i added Super.init()

```
init(calls: APICalls) {
    super.init()
    self.calls = calls
}
```

And now i get this error:

> super.init cannot be called outside of an initializer

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Please show `Router` implementation (initializer wize).

Comment: There no initializes in Router

Comment: That's the problem, then. You need some public initializer for the subclass to call.

Comment: So why does it work on the test target?

Comment: Because you used `@testable`, so you can see internal methods. You need a *public* method to see outside the framework. Get rid of `@testable` and I bet it has the same behavior as other importers.

Comment: something related to this https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2295?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to declare an empty `public init() {}` in `Router`.

Though it's a cryptic error, the problem is that the subclass cannot call `super.init()` because that initializer is not accessible outside of the `NetworkManager` module unless you declare it as `public`. The automatically-generated `init()` in `Router` is not `public` by default.

It worked in your test class because the `@testable import` sidestepped the default `internal` access restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create an Inheritance feature of the Swift Programming.

I created the `ViewController` as super class.
Then I created another class as subclass name as `ViewControllerA` of  super class `ViewController`

**ViewController Class :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  //: public variables
  var area:               CGFloat?


  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  public func printArea(){
      print("Print area in Super class")
  }

  public func calculateArea(){

  }

}
```

**ViewControllerA as subclass :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: ViewController {

    var length:                 CGFloat?


     init( len: CGFloat) {
        self.length = len
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func printArea() {
        print("The are of A \(area!)")
    }


    override func calculateArea() {
        area = length! * length!
    }
}
```

I have got the error.
`Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'ViewController'` in subclass init method.

So I declare the empty `init` method in super class i.e `ViewController`

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

It worked for me.